# What is MonkeyCom on port 9898?

Tags: linux, unix, port, service

In `/etc/services` on a few machines I've checked, port 9898 is associated with a service called MonkeyCom:

```
monkeycom   9898/udp     # MonkeyCom
monkeycom   9898/tcp     # MonkeyCom
```

The [first reference](http://www.monkeygumbo.com/news/mt/mt-comments.cgi?entry_id=159) I found in a google search for MonkeyCom says it's part of the Sasser virus. That seems like a misinterpretation to me -- it's more likely that Sasser is using 9898 but that there's some older service called MonkeyCom which originally got the assignment.

Who can tell me what MonkeyCom is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MonkeyCom is (or was - as far as I can determine it is now defunct) a videophone/file transfer program.
As far as I can determine nothing legitimate is currently using port 9898 - it's pretty much just Sasser and a few other bits of nasty.

Comment: Do you have a source for that defunct videophone program or the reference to it?

Comment: http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/10825_3521746_2/Whats-All-That-Text-Mean--Learn-Linux-Logging.htm is the most authoritative one I found.  The referenced site is long gone however & makes no mention of the MonkeyCom product.

Comment: Old but still useful thread. -- Consider `pgpool` as a prime candidate to be the root-cause for this false positive. As suggested by @JoeVanDyk below,  `lsof | grep ":9898"` or `lsof -i :9898` may not reveal 'pgpool' even though its is installed as middleware and part of a `posgresql` setup. Better look at yr FW activity log to see what really makes yr 9898 TCP port look busy/open. `nmap` will sometimes report "monkeycom" as the associated application, a false positive for a "Dabber/Sasser" type worm infection (prevalent among M$ Win users). "False" as in _it is really not there_ !

Comment: Thank the Internet Archive for this page: https://web.archive.org/web/20040603165425/http://www.random-grp.com/kuwatec/Products/MonkeyCom/. Using Google translate, the opening description says "MonkeyCom is a personal communication tool that allows you to easily transfer files between two computers connected via a telephone line using a modem or directly connected via serial cable or network."

Comment: 9898 port is used in Xiaomi Mi Smart Home Hub device (if enabled).

Answer (score 9):

Tripwire Enterprise uses 9898 as it's default port for communication between server and agent.

Comment: I can conrirm that the tripwire agent is running on this port with an enterprise license on my machines. I would have voted up the first tripwire suggestion but don't have the rep points yet.

Answer (score 3):

pgpool might be using that port.

You can do a "lsof | grep 9898" and check.

Comment: Or lsof -i :9898

Comment: +1 for mentioning `pgpool`.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive source for Port Assignments is IANA http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers from which you can find a name and email address of someone who might know the answer to your question. More probably the email address is no longer valid :-(

Answer (score 0):

Echoing RedGrittyBrick's point. Came across the same. MonkeyCom is a port association for a legitimate program which is likely also exploited in other instances.

Check out the following [listing](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) for a bit more detail